# Center SVG in its viewport

Tags: css

I have the following SVG:

```html
<svg width="15px" height="18px" viewBox="0 0 15 18" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Shape</title>
    <g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="question-controls" transform="translate(-52.000000, -1.000000)" fill="#72758D" fill-rule="nonzero">
            <path d="M62,1 L54,1 C52.9,1 52,1.9 52,3 L52,13 L54,13 L54,3 L62,3 L62,1 Z M65,5 L58,5 C56.9,5 56,5.9 56,7 L56,17 C56,18.1 56.9,19 58,19 L65,19 C66.1,19 67,18.1 67,17 L67,7 C67,5.9 66.1,5 65,5 Z M65,17 L58,17 L58,7 L65,7 L65,17 Z" id="Shape"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It is a "Duplicate Icon" from Material IO.
https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=duplicat&icon=content_copy&style=baseline

However, as can you see it is not centered in its view port.
[image]

I tried by giving the same `viewBox` value like `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` with little success.

Comment: Can you add code for the containing element too?

Comment: What is highlight in the image is the `viewBox`, not a `div`

Comment: Your snippet doesn't demonstrate that